# Angular js and ionic

Tags: angularjs

how do i post html login form to php login form  in a different url using angular js controller  and returning success when the login credential is correct and failure when the credentials are wrong.below is my existing Controller and intends to use it together with my html login page while it posts/authenticates the login.php and returns success or failure upon input credentials

```
 .controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $ionicViewService, $http, DataStore) {
    $scope.domain = DataStore.domain;
    var urlpath = DataStore.domain+'/login.php';

    $("#username").focus();
    $("#username, #password").keyup(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length !== 0) {
            $("#validate").hide();
        }
    });

    //Authenticates blank fields
    $("#login").on('click', function () {
        if ($("#username").val() == '') {
            $("#validate").html("username is required").show();
            $("#username").focus();

        }
        else if ($("#password").val() == '') {
            $("#validate").html("Password is required").show();
            $("#password").focus();
        }

        else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: urlpath,
                data: $('#myloginform').serialize(),
                success: function (html) {
                var resp = html.split(":");
                 // alert(resp[0]);
                 if (resp[0] == 'success') {
                     $("#validate").html("Wrong username or password").show();
                 }else {

                     $state.go('menu.home');
                    }
                }

            });

         // todo: Login is actually done here

          //todo: validate the login

          $ionicViewService.nextViewOptions({
            disableBack: true
          });
             //$state.go('menu.home');
          return false;
           };


    })
})
```

Comment: AngularJS is a framework which helps you make *single-page applications*, meaning there are no page changes, and all communication to the server are done through async requests (AJAX). So you will have to use AJAX. Please provide more information about what you are trying to do (maybe pseudo-code) and what you have tried so far.

Comment: You shouldn't be using jQuery in angularjs, you are already doing it wrong. You can create "services and factories" for making async http requests. Authentication should happen in the html not the js code. Please provide some pseudo-code to clarify the problem.

Comment: ok, help me with a correct clue or a template to post to html form to php form and return result of the login

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource - restful async http, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http - a bit lower level, I tend to wrap $http in a Service object. Prepare to do a bit of google searching as the Angular docs aren't completely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried coding an

```
else {
    $http.post('http://localhost:0000', data).success(successCallback);
}
```

Localhost would be the ip or url of the server you are wishing to send the post data to.